# Best complexity bound for parallel matrix-vector product?

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, matrices, matrix-product, parallel

I'm looking for the best known complexity (and a bound for the number of processors invoved) to do the calculation of a $(n,n)$ matrix-vector product.

Thank you

Comment: Is that of theoretical or of practical importance for you? (I do not know the answer to the question)